# Get String of a single firebase recycler view item android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have list of children in my `firebase real time database` which am retrieving into `firebase ui recycler view`. The `model` parameter fetches me a list of string from all my views. What i want however is to retrieve a single string from the particular item that was clicked. How do i go round this?

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Sermon, SermonViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Sermon, SermonViewHolder>(Sermon.class, R.layout.item_view, SermonViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(SermonViewHolder viewHolder, Sermon model, int position) {

                final String audioLink = model.getAudioLink(); 
// This retrieves data from all the data model at the same. I need string for the particular item clicked.

            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `setOnClickListener` method inside `populateViewHolder`

```
 viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     //Retrieve your string from model object using position variable
                    //which is an argument in `populateViewHolder` method
                    }
                  });
```

Comment: Your welcome, Update here if something more occurs in this!